# Security implications of HTTP GET with REST web service

Tags: c#, wcf, security, rest, http-get

I have used an approach very similar to the one to implement an Api Key approach to identifying which clients use a web service:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2010/06/14/how-to-do-api-key-verification-for-rest-services-in-net-4.aspx

The question I have is about security... the service was put through some security testing by a third party company.  One of their "low-risk" comments (i.e. one that does not require immediate attention), is that parameters are passed as httpget.  The service is purely for retrieving information. However, the apikey is in the query string... e.g. a URL might be

https://url.com/companies?company_name=searchforthiscompany&address=paris&apikey=a-long-guid

"Implication: 
When parameters are passed as part of HTTP Get requests, they are more likely to
be stored in intermediate or other server log files. A curious user can potentially see
sensitive information such as the APIKey.

Recommendation:
If possible, parameters should be passed as part of the HTTP POST body."

Should this be something I need to worry about?!  It is nice to be able to just whack a URL into a browser and get back results.  Would you change all of your methods to use POST in this case?

Any insight appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Since your requests are over https no intermediate will be able to log the complete uri, just the domain, since a secure tunnel is established and all exchanges are done through this.

Answer (score 1):

Well it all depends on how secure you *need* your service to be. If security is not a relevant concern, then by all means, use GET. Many public REST webservices are implemented with the api_key directly passed in the url. An example that comes to mind is the flickr service to retrieve photos:

http://api.flickr.com/services/rest?method=flickr.photos.search&lat=41.20&lon=12.10&radius=10&api_key=e61cfc16c8633091c57557146d169874